# How can I pause in a shell script?

Tags: shell, shell-script

How can I make my shell script pause before continuing?

Comment: instead of assuming it doesn't exist, maybe you should assume you were unable to find it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You mean [`sleep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sleep)?  Or do you want to have something that waits for input before continuing?  You can do that with a [`read`](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html) call.

Comment: `read` is what I was looking for! Unfortunately, it's not present in my embedded system (using busybox).. :(

Comment: @Tom Brito: `read` is a shell builtin; you won't find it in /bin. Does it really not work in your busybox shell? (it works in mine, but I guess maybe its possible to compile busybox w/o it)

Comment: @derobert ops! yes, it's there! sorry

Answer (score 0):

He might also be looking for CTRL-Z, which pauses the current process.

Comment: not, I'm looking for a command line..